# Using 'parallel' to execute command on remote hosts - nothing is returned, failed logins

Tags: ssh, password, remote, gnu-parallel

I am trying to execute simple 'parallel' command

```
parallel -S server1,server2,server3 echo "Number {}: Running on \`hostname\`" ::: 1 2 3
```

It asks me for passwords to the three servers, but then nothing happens. Usual ssh to these servers works fine.

Once I logged in to one of the servers, system warned me about failed login to 'notty'.

How can I achieve a correct execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### "It asks me for passwords to the three servers"

Looking at the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html) for GNU Parallel:

*"The sshlogin must not require a password"*

Since you are using the `-S` (--sshlogin) flag this is a problem.

So you get asked for a password, this means GNU Parallel will not run.

You need to set up ssh keys to ensure you can have password-less connections.

You can follow the steps in [this](https://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/) link to set up keys.

You do say in your post that normal ssh works fine. So you maybe have ssh set up to ask for password. You can use your existing keys and add them to the `authorized_keys` file if this is the case.